# Run JS in script only after page load

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write some JS in the `<head>` of the document that changes some text after a date search is performed. Specifically, if the search did not show any results based on those dates.

This is via a code snippet section in the website builder, so I do not have direct access to the document. Only adding JS into `<script><script/>` that is added to the `<head>` of the doc.

I have tried:

```
<script>

document.getElementsByClassName("font-size-md")[0].setAttribute("id", "myId");
document.getElementById("myId");
myId.innerHTML = "Write Your Text Here";

</script>
```

This only modified the inner HTML after a refresh of the page.

I have also tried:

```
<script>

body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.onload = function() {
document.getElementsByClassName("font-size-md")[0].setAttribute("id", "myId");
document.getElementById("myId");
myId.innerHTML = "Write Your Text Here";
};

</script>
```

However, this seems to flat out not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can have a look at `window.onload` vs `document.onload`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload

Comment: Place the code at the end of the document.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need jQuery for it:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
         // your code
  });
</script>
```

Comment: So I used

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
document.getElementsByClassName("font-size-md")[0].setAttribute("id", "myId");
document.getElementById("myId");
myId.innerHTML = "Write Your Text Here";
 });
</script>
```
However, it does render the modified HTML at all at this point. Any clue why?

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand the problem.

Comment: My bad, there was a typo. I meant to say "However, it does NOT render the modified HTML at all at this point. Any clue why?"

Answer (score -1):

put the script below the `<body></body>` tag

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // do stuff
    });
</script>
```

or you can use jquery

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // do stuff
    });
</script>
```